# Find an example to show that it is necessary to assume that X is Hausdorff for the set $\{x\in X | f(x)=x\}$ to be closed.

Tags: general-topology, separation-axioms

I need help with this exercise.

I have just proven that if X is a Hausdorff space, and $f: X\to X$ is a continuous function, then the set $\{x\in X | f(x)=x\}$ is closed in X. Now I need to find an example to show that it is necessary to assume that X is Hausdorff for this set to be closed. i.e I am thinking that I have to find a set X which is not Hausdorff such that $\{x\in X | f(x)=x\}$ is not closed. But I am a little confused about how to choose X, and how to after that show that the set $\{x\in X | f(x)=x\}$ is not closed.

Comment: Consider $X=\{0,1\}$ with the trivial topology (that is not Hausdorff) and $f(x)=0$. The set of fixed points is $\{0\}$ that is not closed because the only closed sets in the triviual topology are $\emptyset$ and $X$

Answer (score 1):

Take $X= \Bbb Z$ in the cofinite topology. This is $T_1$ but not Hausdorff.

Define $f(n) = n$ for all $n \ge 0$ and $ f(n)=n-1$ for $ n <0$. Then the set of fixed points is $\Bbb Z^+$ which is not finite so not closed while $f$, as any injection , is continuous on $X$.

Comment: @SolubleFish injection is all I need.or finite-to-one.